# A Wrong statement about Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

As I was studying Calculus from -$Thomas$ $and$ $Finney$- I came across the following statement in exercise:

> Wrong statement about limits
>
> Show by example that the following statement is wrong :
>
> The no. L is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $x_o$ if ,given any $\epsilon \gt 0$,there exists a value of $x$ for which $|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$.

I can't understand what's wrong with the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x$, let $x_0= 1000$, and let $L=0$. Given any $\epsilon>0$, choosing $x=0$ gives $|f(x)-L|=0<\epsilon$, but $\lim_{x \to 1000} f(x)=1000$.

One issue with the statement is that the $x$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ may be far away from $x_0$, but the limit deals with the behavior of $f$ near $x_0$.

Comment: Good answer :-) Your example is easier to understand than mine, I think. I like mine because you can choose the $x$ arbitrarily close to $x_0$ and still satisfy the condition (which, I must admit, is how I read it). +$1$

Comment: @Clayton Thanks! Indeed, your example touches on the subtler issue with the original statement.

Comment: @angryavian I liked the answer one thing I want to clarify the thing that is wrong with the statement is that simply choosing $x$ s.t. $|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon $ does not imply f(x) approaches $x_o$..

Comment: @angryavian I mean what additional thing should have been added to ensure limit is L

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract The definition of limit is that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for any $x$ satisfying $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Unlike the "wrong statement" above, this definition captures the idea that $f$ is close to $L$ (this is $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$) _everywhere near_ $x_0$ (this is $|x-x_0|<\delta$).

Comment: @angryavian I understood that the ensuring an interval is more necessary than just a point as in case of Clayton's answer because it tells the behaviour of all the points in the interval that they are close to L everytime we choose an $\epsilon $..

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract Yes, that is right. Do you have a question?

Comment: @angryavian there was another wrong statement as question which said:  the no. L is said to be limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $x_o$ if $f(x)$ gets closer to L as $x$ approaches $x_o$.I feel it is incorrect because if we take any monotonically increasing function and its any upper bound except the least upper bound the above statement is true but it is not the limit .Am I correct..

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract Sure, that works. As another example, consider $f(x)=x^2$, $x_0=0$, and $L=-1$. As $x\to 0$, the function gets closer to $-1$, but the limit is $0$.

Comment: @angryavian thanks for clarifying..

Comment: @angryavian The problem statement says "as x approaches $x_0$", but this part is ignored in the answer. $x_0 = 1000$ would not be close to x = 0

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider a function like $\chi_{\Bbb Q}(x)$, which is $1$ on the rationals and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: what does $\chi_{\Bbb Q}(x)$ mean .does it mean that the value of x is coming from rationals.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract $$\chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \notin \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

Comment: In general, for a subset $A$ of the real numbers, the characteristic function $\chi_A(x)$ is defined to be $1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.